# Obj-C gRPC new API receiving RST_STREAM error

Tags: objective-c, grpc

## Context

- Have a Obj-C app that needs to consume some server data. The communication uses gRPC.
- Created a Obj-C client using `!ProtoCompiler-gRPCPlugin" and "ProtoCompiler".
- Using `protoc` we generated the client. This client exposes two APIs for the same call: One is called "apiV1" and is deprecated, the other is "apiV2" and is suggested.
- Below is an example of both:

```c
 /* This method belongs to a set of APIs that have been deprecated. Using the v2 API is recommended.
 */
- (void)someCallWithRequest:(XXXCallRequest *)request handler:(void(^)(XXXCallResponse *_Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error))handler;
```

And, now, the new suggested API:

```c
- (GRPCUnaryProtoCall *)callWithMessage:(XXXCallRequest *)message responseHandler:(id<GRPCProtoResponseHandler>)handler callOptions:(GRPCCallOptions *_Nullable)callOptions;
```

## The problem

When we use the suggested v2 API, some of our calls receives the `RST_STREAM` error:

```
Error Domain=io.grpc Code=13 "{"created":"@1589553479.630057000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:x.x.x.x:443","file":"/Users/me/Documents/ourapp/App/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}" UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={
    date = "Fri, 15 May 2020 14:37:58 GMT";
    server = "nginx/1.17.8";
    "strict-transport-security" = "max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains";
    trailer = "Grpc-Status";
}, io.grpc.TrailersKey={
}, NSDebugDescription={"created":"@1589553479.630057000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:x.x.x.:443","file":"/Users/me/Documents/ourapp/App/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1056,"grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 2","grpc_status":13}, NSLocalizedDescription=Received RST_STREAM with error code 2}.
```

Here's how we are using the new gRPC API:

```
GRPCMutableCallOptions *callOptions = [self buildCallOptions];
XXXCallService *service = [XXXCallService serviceWithHost:host callOptions:callOptions];
XXXCallRequest *callRequestMessage = [self buildCallRequest];

[[service callWithMessage:callRequestMessage
               responseHandler:[[GRPCUnaryResponseHandler alloc] initWithResponseHandler:^(XXXCallResponse* response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) NSLog(@"%@.", error);
}
```

And, the most important: when we use the deprecated V1 API, this error *never* happens. But, unfortunately, it does not have support for defining the CallOptions/metadata/headers, which we require right now.

Comment: The above error happened for me with the deprecated v1 api as well but for stream connection